# Mapping resources to classes in C#/WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, internationalization

I have a bunch of `Shape`-classes (classic) like `Rectangle` and `Circle` in my first module.

In my second module, I have a GUI, made with WPF. I want to show a `ListBox` of all `Shape`-classes. The `ListBox` shall contain the localizable name of the shape, which is saved as a resource string, and an icon, saved as a resource image.

I want my whole code to be as modular as possible, e.g. if I add a new `Shape`-class, I want to change as few classes as possible.

My first approach would be to make a helper class in my GUI-module, which for each shape holds the `Shape`'s `Type`, its name as `string`, and its icon as a `Bitmap` (or similar). I would then initialize the list at one place, e.g.

```
var shapeList = new List<ShapeHelperClass>
{
  new ShapeHelperClass(typeof(Rectangle), Resources.StringRectangle, Resources.IconRectangle),
  new ShapeHelperClass(typeof(Circle), Resources.StringCircle, Resources.IconCircle),
};
```

and bind this list to the `ListBox`. Now, if I rename my classes or my resources, nothing will break, and localization should work properly. But, of course, if adding a new `Shape`-class in the first module, I also need to update this list.

Another approach would be to use reflection to find all my `Shape` classes, and build the list out of that. However, I would still need some Dictionaries or something similar to map the classes to the Resources. I could find the resources if they follow a pattern, like "Icon" + "Classname". However, if no icon is found, this is only noticed at runtime.

So, my questions are:

1. Is my first approach a good one, our could it be improved?
2. How can I make sure that a programmer who adds a new `Shape` also adds the new Resources and extends the mapping-list? Maybe by Unit-testing?

Comment: List/dictionary to resolve resource is fine, reflection is better if you want automatic resolving (new shape is added). It may make sense to add to `Shape` abstract members to resolve resource and text.

Comment: @Sinatr: I wouldn't want to add abstract members `Icon` and `Name` to `Shape`, since that is only a part of the GUI, and not neccessary for the class itself. And yes, reflection will automatically find new classes. The problem is that the reflector can't make up names and icons for those new classes ;-)

Comment: I misunderstood your question, you are using `System.Windows.Shapes` and not a custom `Shape` class. Obviously you can't add anything to it. Resolver class with `Dictionary<Type, Info>` sounds appropriate to resolve `Info` about certain shape type. You can provide a static method to *register* new shape type (it's common pattern and used by e.g. attached properties in wpf). Another option is to contain this data as type *metadata* - use attributes, for standard classes you must define list/dictionary, for newly made - resolve via attributes.

Comment: @Sinatr No, it's not the Windows-`Shape`-class, but custom classes... Anyway, that was just an example, it could be anything else...

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Is my first approach a good one, our could it be improved?

You could create a method in your first module that returns all shapes and call this one in your client application, e.g.:

```
var shapes = GetShapes();
List<ShapeHelperClass> helpers = new List<ShapeHelperClass>();
foreach(var shape in shapes)
    helpers.Add(...);
```

Then you should never have to modify the client application as a shape is added or removed in the first module.

> 2.How can I make sure that a programmer who adds a new Shape also adds the new Resources and extends the mapping-list? Maybe by Unit-testing?

Maybe you could write a unit test that uses reflection to find all shape types and asserts that they are included in the list of shapes that is returned from the first module. And likewise for the resources. I can't think of any better automatic way of ensuring this really.

Comment: "Then you should never have to modify the client application as a shape is added or removed in the first module." -> Well, I would still have to add the resources, which of course is inevitable...

Comment: "You could create a method in your first module that returns all shapes and call this one in your client application [...]" -> How would you imagine the `GetShapes()`-Method? I mean, either it is a hardcoded list in the first module, then I could also forget to add the new `Shape` to it. Or it uses Reflection, but then again I could use reflection from the GUI-module and would not really need this function...

Comment: Using reflection in GUI module sounds like a bad idea. The logic of finding all shapes should not be implemented in the UI. It should be encapsulated in the other module. And of course you must still add the shapes and the resources to your application somewhere.